# Problema con Autenticacion de laravel 5.6

Tags: mysql, laravel

tengo un problema con la autenticacion de laravel.. Tengo un proyecto en mi repositorio de github.. un dia cambie mi sistema y entonces clone de vuelta el proyecto para seguir trabajando.. entonces quise loguearme en el sistema y me salta un mensaje que me dice que **estas credenciales no coinciden con nuestros registros**, entonces mire en mi phpmyadmin para ver si estaba o no mi cuenta y si estaba. Entonces crei que era un problema en mi codigo porque habia modificado un poco el sistema de logeo, pero no, clone otro proyecto y me saltaba lo mismo, Probe en otra maquina para sacarme de las dudas y me sigue saltando el mismo mensaje, no se si entienden mi problema o si explique mal pero este problema lo tengo con todos los proyectos que estoy clonando... alguna ayuda respecto a esto?

Comment: Bueno al final lo resolví entrando a esta pagina https://www.browserling.com/tools/bcrypt , era un problema con la encriptacion del password. Tuve que encriptar mi clave y luego copiarla a mi base de datos y funciono.. la verdad sigo sin entender porque pasa esto porque antes no tenia este tipo de problemas.

Comment: Si estás usando la autenticación de Laravel que viene "recién salida de la caja", siempre ha pedido la contraseña encriptada usando el método `bcrypt()`, al menos a partir de la versión 5.0 (cuando empecé a usar el framework) lo ha estado haciendo. Si usas el método `attempt()` del facade `Auth` también son necesarias las contraseñas encriptadas.